# Git interface to add files by 'id number'

Tags: git, user-interface

I'm sure I've come across a replacement git interface that provides a number of nicer ways of doing things, but I can't find it again! The key one of these improvements is that when you run `git status` it gives each file in the resulting output a number, and then if you want to add three of these files you can simply run:

```
git add 3 6 11
```

rather than

```
git add doc/source/conf.py src/lib/blah/blah.py src/lib/access.txt
```

After hours of Googling I can't find this extension - does it exist? If so, what is it called, and where can I get it?

Comment: Any chance you mean `git add -i`? I don't recall it allowing to use id numbers, but it has some handy features.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds a bit like you want interactive:

```
git add -i
```

Answer (score 2):

> git-number is a perl script that increases my command-line git
>   productivity (with some help from another two perl scripts).

Repo address : https://github.com/holygeek/git-number

Maybe, this can be useful for you.